# Mapping float values into a new value within a specified range in C++ or Python

Tags: c++, python-2.7, arduino, mapping, accelerometer

I am working with accelerometer data which I need to "map/convert" into a new range of values.

So, of the following example accelerometer data:

```
X: [0.363209]
Y: [0.723211]
Z: [-9.806650]
```

By running my Python script and filtering the maximum and minimum values on all 3 axis', I arrived at the following range of values:

```
LOWEST-X: -47.2172037037
HIGHEST-X: 45.4011574074
LOWEST-Y: -27.6039037037
HIGHEST-Y: 44.6747388889
LOWEST-Z: -49.03325
HIGHEST-Z: 43.3755673077
```

I'm not sure if those ranges are exhaustive as I could not find documentation. So I tossed around my wiimote for a half hour until the figures stopped updating.

I need to convert the **X** accelerometer data into a new value in the range of *-0.22 to 0.22* and the **Y** data into a value in the range of *-2.84 to 2.84*.
I have attempted to accomplish this with the following code:

```
.
.
.
k = self.map(twist.linear.y, -27.6039037037, 44.6747388889, -0.22, 0.22)

print "Testing Y conversion: " + str(k)

def map(self, x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
   return round(float((x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min), 2)
```

That, slightly modified, **map** function is copied from the [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) implementation of the same function.

**However, the mapping output is not reflecting the desired *-0.22 to 0.22* range of output when I move my accelerometer.** Below is a sample of the output of my script:

```
Testing Twist-Y: -2.17925555556  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: 0.726418518519  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 6.53776666667   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 8.71702222222   mapping to:    0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 10.1698592593   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: -1.8160462963   mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: -4.35851111111  mapping to:    -0.08
Testing Twist-Y: -1.8160462963   mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: 3.99530185185   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 4.72172037037   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 6.90097592593   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 6.53776666667   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 0.726418518519  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 0.726418518519  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: -2.17925555556  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 9.44344074074   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 11.259487037    mapping to:    0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 15.6179981481   mapping to:    0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 6.53776666667   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 1.8160462963    mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 7.9906037037    mapping to:    -0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 7.9906037037    mapping to:    -0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 6.90097592593   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 0.726418518519  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 3.99530185185   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 1.08962777778   mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 0.726418518519  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: -3.26888333333  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: 5.08492962963   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: -2.17925555556  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 2.90567407407   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 6.53776666667   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 6.90097592593   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: -1.8160462963   mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: -6.53776666667  mapping to:    -0.09
Testing Twist-Y: 1.8160462963    mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 0.0             mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: -5.08492962963  mapping to:    -0.08
Testing Twist-Y: 0.363209259259  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 3.63209259259   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 1.8160462963    mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 10.8962777778   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 5.08492962963   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 5.08492962963   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 9.80665         mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 9.08023148148   mapping to:    0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 10.1698592593   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 12.7123240741   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 3.63209259259   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: -1.8160462963   mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: -3.26888333333  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: -1.08962777778  mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: 0.726418518519  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 2.17925555556   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 2.17925555556   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 2.17925555556   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 1.08962777778   mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 0.0             mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 2.90567407407   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 6.90097592593   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 7.9906037037    mapping to:    -0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 5.81134814815   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: -0.726418518519 mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 9.80665         mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 10.1698592593   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 7.62739444444   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 10.1698592593   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 9.08023148148   mapping to:    0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 5.81134814815   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 0.0             mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 2.17925555556   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 13.4387425926   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 13.0755333333   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 4.72172037037   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 12.7123240741   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 7.62739444444   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 9.44344074074   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 9.44344074074   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 3.99530185185   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 2.54246481481   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 9.80665         mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 6.53776666667   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 6.17455740741   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 9.08023148148   mapping to:    0.0
Testing Twist-Y: -1.08962777778  mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: -0.363209259259 mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: -0.363209259259 mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 0.363209259259  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 1.8160462963    mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 14.1651611111   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 4.35851111111   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 4.72172037037   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 7.9906037037    mapping to:    -0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 9.44344074074   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 7.62739444444   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 2.54246481481   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 2.90567407407   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 3.99530185185   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 2.17925555556   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 3.63209259259   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 5.81134814815   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 7.9906037037    mapping to:    -0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 6.17455740741   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 0.0             mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: -3.63209259259  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: 4.35851111111   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 13.8019518519   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 9.80665         mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 4.35851111111   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 3.26888333333   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 3.63209259259   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: -1.08962777778  mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: -2.17925555556  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: 7.62739444444   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 3.99530185185   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 3.99530185185   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 3.99530185185   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: -5.08492962963  mapping to:    -0.08
Testing Twist-Y: 0.363209259259  mapping to:    -0.05
Testing Twist-Y: -1.8160462963   mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: -1.8160462963   mapping to:    -0.06
Testing Twist-Y: 1.8160462963    mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 23.2453925926   mapping to:    0.09
Testing Twist-Y: 17.0708351852   mapping to:    0.05
Testing Twist-Y: 14.1651611111   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 6.90097592593   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 4.72172037037   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 5.08492962963   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 8.35381296296   mapping to:    -0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 12.7123240741   mapping to:    0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 10.1698592593   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 10.8962777778   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 4.72172037037   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: -2.90567407407  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: -2.54246481481  mapping to:    -0.07
Testing Twist-Y: 10.5330685185   mapping to:    0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 7.26418518519   mapping to:    -0.01
Testing Twist-Y: 8.71702222222   mapping to:    0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 1.45283703704   mapping to:    -0.04
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 5.44813888889   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 7.9906037037    mapping to:    -0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 5.81134814815   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 4.35851111111   mapping to:    -0.03
Testing Twist-Y: 4.72172037037   mapping to:    -0.02
Testing Twist-Y: 8.71702222222   mapping to:    0.0
Testing Twist-Y: 7.9906037037    mapping to:    -0.0
```

I would like to fine tune or correct this code so the output better reflects the desired range.

Comment: This is simple math if you know the original range of X and Y that you are converting from?

Comment: There are infinitely many such mappings. This is severely under-specified. As it stands, even x \mapsto 0 would fulfill the requirements you state.

Comment: Do you know the range of values, i.e. the maximal and minimal value, that the accelerometer will output for each coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

Assume input range is `xmin...xmax`, and output range is `xmin'...xmax'`, so

```
x'(xmin) = xmin'
x'(xmax) = xmax'
```

Then

```
x'  = xmin' + (x - xmin) * (xmax'-xmin') / (xmax-xmin) = xmin' + k * (x - xmin)
```

where

`k = (xmax'-xmin') / (xmax-xmin)`

Another case, if you need to clamp the value in a certain interval:

```
x'(x) = x, xmin < x < xmax
x'(x) = xmin,  x <= xmin
x'(x) = xmax,  x >= xmax
```

In this case, you need

```
newx = std::clamp(x, xmin, xmax); // since C++17
```

Or

```
newx = std::max(xmin, std::min(x, xmax));
```

Answer (score 1):

Transforms as follows assuming original range of 0 to 1:

```
x * 4.4 - 2.2
y * 5.68 - 2.84
```

Transforms as follows assuming original range of -1 to 1

```
x * 2.2
y * 2.84
```

Transforms as follows assuming original range of a to b

```
(x - a) * 4.4 / (b - a) - 2.2
(y - a) * 5.68 / (b - a) - 2.84
```

Comment: I appreciate your input Jaybird but I don't understand it.
I've made my question more verbose if it will help clarify my issues.

Comment: If you could please print out the original `twist.linear.y` value as well as `k` then I can verify the maths, because the logic looks right at first glance.

Comment: I updated the sample output in my question to contain twist.linear.y values and the values they currently map to.

Comment: As I wondered, the input values don't come close to the min and max values you determined. If you want to stretch the values out towards their extremes I'd suggest a cubic mapping, although I'm not too sure what the equation would be off the top of my head. A simpler idea would be to bring the input min and max values closer to zero (even half them, if not more), then clamp any outliers. "if x > in_max, return out_max".

Comment: I was afraid of that. I could not find documentation on the wiimote which states what the lowest and highest value on each of the axis'.
I got the range figures I have by running a python script and saving the highest and lowest values for each axis.